# Pandas datetime index.is_quarter_end error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to extract only the months at the end of each quarter from my dataframe:

```py
sim_rets = pd.DataFrame(rets.T, index= pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2006,7,1) ,freq = 'bM', periods=192))

sim_rets.loc[sim_rets.index.is_quarter_end]
```

But I get the error

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 sim_rets.loc[sim_rets.index.is_quarter_end]

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'is_quarter_end'

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of `pandas` are you using? Please share sample data in your description so it's easy to replicate. Thanks!

Comment: My pandas version is 0.13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an old pandas version of Pandas, `v0.13.1`. Check the source code in Github [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.13.1/pandas/core/base.py). You need to upgrade the version to `v0.14.0` or later, source code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.14.0/pandas/core/base.py#L372) when it was added to pandas. Example below but more [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#history):

`pip install pandas==0.14.0`